# Division of a negative number by a positive number

Tags: number-theory

If $-17$ is divided by $3$ below which will be the correct result and why?

1. Quotient is $-5$ and remainder $-2$
2. Quotient is $-6$ and remainder $+1$

Comment: In some sense they're both correct. If you have to choose between them, you will have to take a good look at your book's / teacher's / notes' _definition_ of division with remainder and see what those say. Once you've done that, you should be able to choose which one fulfills the demands of your defininition.

Comment: Mostly the remainder is asked to be nonnegative (and smaller than the divisor of course). That approach has my preference.

Comment: If I remember rightly, it's usual to take the one with the smallest possible positive remainder, but I agree with @Arthur, check your teacher's definition

Comment: @lioness99a You probably mean "nonnegative" (instead of "positive").

Comment: @drhab What's the difference, positive $\Leftrightarrow$ nonnegative, does it not?

Comment: @lioness99a then what is the remainder if $9$ is divided by $3$? It is $0$ which is not positive and is nonnegative.

Comment: @drhab $0$ is considered both positive or negative in my understanding

Comment: @lioness99a Then you are quite lonesome in that understanding. Have a look [here](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_number).

Comment: @drhab lioness99a's understanding is the widespread one: zero is both negative and positive. Your link doesn't contradict that.

Comment: @Evargalo in the link it is evidently contradicted. In a definition "if" must be interpreted as "if and only if". So the link tells us that zero is not positive because zero is not biggen than zero.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is "more" correct: if you are given $n$ and $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ with $m\neq 0$ then there exist unique $q$, $r$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ with $0\leq r < |m|$ such that $n=q\cdot m + r$. See e.g. Theorem 2 of [these notes](http://www.math.udel.edu/~lazebnik/papers/ElementsThNum.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

On a number line all addition operations in multiplication should go in the same direction.The remainder is what's left to go in that direction not what you have already left behind.
To me the first answer is acceptable and the second is not.Because that will be like going in one direction and then coming backwards